# Using HTML with Flex 4?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, builder

How do I add HTML inside my Flex app just like the one Tour De Flex uses.

Here's a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/JH6X1qUBNLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML Component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5).  It is AIR only, so you won't be able to do this in a web based app.

For a web based app, you'll want to use the [iFrame trick](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex+iFrame&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: @Shedo Depending on the extents of the HTML that need to be interpreted could also potentially use http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/06/displaying-html-formatted-text-in-a-spark-richtext-control-in-flex-4/ but this is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

The tag <mx:TextArea> can have a nested <mx:htmlText> tag that can contain HTML code.
For example:

```
<mx:TextArea id="htmlTextWillAppear"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    borderStyle="none"
    editable="false"
    condenseWhite="true">    
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
            <p>This is where the HTML will go icluding Links, images, unordered lists, et.</p>
        ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:TextArea>
```

The CDATA tag is needed so that the Flex compiler knows to interpret what follows literally and not as MXML tags.

I use this method to pupulate the text in my Flex website that provides [tutorials for creating accessible Flex content](http://www.accessiblerichinternetapplication.com/).